# Using perl to talk to serial port for sat comms

Tags: perl, serial-port

This is probably an easy one, but I need to use perl to both talk to a serial port, and accept responses back from it - ideally something which would flag up to the rest of my programme that a new message has come back from the port so that I can process it?

The unit I'm using is called a RockBLOCK, it's a two-way satellite communicator module, plugs into the USB port, but presents itself as a normal serial device. Details here in case anyone is interested: http://rockblock.rock7mobile.com

Does anyone have any sample code for sending data plus also flagging if a message has come back? The first bit seems fairly straighforward, but the second less so...

Comment: Linux - I'm using a Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching CPAN for the obvious terms gives me [Device::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Device%3A%3ASerialPort) and [Win32::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3A%3ASerialPort) which both seem to do exactly what you need.

Comment: THank you - sorry for such a newbie question, I'll take a look at those and see if I can make it work with that. Thanks